# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compilation, dsl

I am adding the makovkastar/FloatingActionButton to my project and when I try to sync the gradle files I get the Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' error. I am new to gradle and not sure what to do. I have read around and it says to use the build.gradle in your modules directory. I believe that I am doing that. So any help would be much appreciated!

Here is a snippet from my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
        maven { url 'http://repository.codehaus.org' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0'
        //classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.14.7'
        classpath 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.18.0'
        compile 'com.github.makovkastar:FloatingActionutton:35379c7962'
    }
}
```

Comment: add compile line in your module gradle file not app gradle file. i think above is not your module directory

Comment: Thanks. That has removed that error. Now I am getting a Failed to resolve: 'com.github.makovkastar:FloatingActionButton:35379c7962'

Comment: I forgot to add the repository... Thanks for you help